# why do I need type casting when printf negative interger value

Tags: c++

The following code prints a very large integer value, not -1.

```
int64_t num = -1
printf("%lld",num);
```

I need to type casting to print -1.

```
printf("%lld",(int64_t) num);
```

Does any one know why??
Is it standard? or undefined behavior that can vary depending on the system platform?

I use x86 intel processor and intel icc compiler.

Comment: @DenisSheremet I use x86 intel processor and intel icc compiler.

Comment: Better post a [mcve]. In `num` is `int64_t`, the cast won't do anything.

Comment: Are you writing C or C++? In C++, you'd use `std::cout` instead of `printf`.

Comment: @MSalters `printf` is part of Standard C++

Comment: It works for me:  cpp.sh/8aw6z (note that with this compiler %lld expect long long, but int64_t is long, so I fixed the type).

Comment: @M.M: Of course. I still maintain that "In C++ you'd use `std::cout`". Not because `printf` is unavailable, but because it's type-unsafe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your code is not *strictly* well-defined.

In order to output a `int64_t` type (which, if your compiler support it, must be a 2's complement 64 bit `signed` type), you need to first write

```
#include <cinttypes>
```

Then use `PRId64` as the format specfier:

```
printf("%" PRId64, num);
```

If you have the comparitive luxury of C++, you can use the considerably simpler `std::cout` which will have an appropriate overload for `int64_t`, assuming your platform implements that type.

Comment: You are correct, but in *practise* with icc, I think it will behave the same.  I don't think the OP is showing us the actual code that he is having trouble with.